# MATLAB Remove rows with second/third occurence of duplicate index

Tags: matlab, matrix, unique

I have a large matrix with two columns. First is an index, second is data. Some indices are repeated. How can I retain only the first instance of rows with repeated indices?

For Example:

```
x = 
    1   5.5
    1   4.5
    2   4
    3   2.5
    3   3
    4   1.5
```

to end up with:

```
ans = 
    1   5.5
    2   4
    3   2.5
    4   1.5
```

I've tried various variations and iterations of

```
[Uy, iy, yu] = unique(x(:,1));
[q, t] = meshgrid(1:size(x, 2), yu);
totals = accumarray([t(:), q(:)], x(:));
```

but nothing so far has given me the output I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `'first'` tag in the `unique` function and then the second output supplies you with the row indices you want which you can use to 'filter' your matrix.

```
[~, ind] = unique(x(:,1), 'first');
ans = x(ind, :)

ans =

    1.0000    5.5000
    2.0000    4.0000
    3.0000    2.5000
    4.0000    1.5000
```

**EDIT**

or as Jonas points out (esp for old Matlab releases)

```
[~, ind] = unique(flipud(x(:,1)));
ans = x(flipud(ind), :)
```

Comment: This behavior is only supported in more recent releases. For releases where `unique` would return the index of the last element, call `flipud` on `x` first.

Comment: @Jonas It's already supported in R2008a, not sure if you can call it "recent".

Comment: Thanks @Jonas, added `flipud` method for legacy Matlab users

Comment: Success! still getting to grips with index vectors in unique outputs. I'll get there eventually! Thanks very much all.

Comment: Is it possible to then extract the data for the second/third occurrence of those that have multiple indices? I know that `'last'` would do the same for the last occurrence, but could I specify 'second' or 'third'?

Comment: I think you might have to do that iteratively'

Comment: Remove the 'first' occurences and then call 'first' again to get the second?

Comment: I'd need to keep the indices and fill in all the spaces (where the index only occurs once) with NaN. I have a very awkward dataset. It's a right pain.